# jboss_cli active sessions details

Tags: jboss, wildfly-9, jboss-cli

I am pretty new to jboss and am wondering if we can get the details about the active sessions on a deployment.

*For count its possible via /deployment=DEPLOYMENT.war/subsystem=undertow/:read-attribute(name=active-sessions)*

But I am looking into if I can list out all the active connections with some details? and if required can kill any one based on my requirement via jboss_cli?

Any guidance or help will be really appreciated.

Thank you,
Sunny

Comment: What kind of details are you looking for? Have a look at https://docs.wildfly.org/19/wildscribe/deployment/subsystem/undertow/index.html too. There is a `invalidate-sessions` operation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No longer required, found an alternative instead of jboss fixed the issue from FE level.